# Calculate the sum of the following series : $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k*x^k}{3^k*k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I need to calculate the following series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k \cdot x^k}{3^k*k}$$

This is what I've done, and for some reason its wrong.

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k\cdot\frac{x^k}{3^k\cdot k} =$$
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k+1}\cdot \frac{x^{k+1}}{3^{k+1}\cdot (k+1)} =$$
$$-\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}\cdot \frac{x^{k+1}}{3^{k+1}\cdot (k+1)} =$$
$$-\sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^{k}\cdot \frac{(\frac{x}{3})^{k+1}}{(k+1)} =$$
$$-\ln(1+\frac{x}{3})$$

I don't understand what's wrong with my answer? Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: @Chappers I checked on wolframalpha and the answer is $ln(3)-ln(x+3)$

Comment: is the same thing....

Comment: @sandstone Oh, I didn't knew that.

Comment: which is remarkable as you knew the taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$

Comment: @sandstone I know that $$ln(1+x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k* \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$$

Comment: Did you not learn http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities in high school?

Comment: @sandstone Well, I studied math in a really low level in high school, therefore I have some "holes" like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this concrete,
$$\log{ab}=\log{a}+\log{b}.$$
From this we can deduce
$$ 0 = \log{1}, $$
and hence
$$ \log{a}+\log{(1/a)} = \log{1}=0, $$
so $\log{(1/a)}=-\log{a}$. You then have
$$ -\log{\left(1+\frac{x}{3}\right)} = -\log{\left( \frac{3+x}{3} \right)} = -\log{(3+x)}+\log{3}. $$

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know logarithm, you can still solve the problem.Let f(x) be the expression,then f'(x) is a geometric series and you can find the sum.Then you can integrate it to get back f(x).

Comment: If OP doesn't understand logs, I think it unlikely that they understand derivatives.